# Number of even sized partitions of $\{ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

> What is the cardinality of $N$ where
>   $$N=\{P\mid P \, \text{is a partition of }\, \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\},\text{ and } |P| \text{ is even}\}$$

#### My ideas:

The number of all partitions is the Bell number $B_8= 4140$.

But how can I find the number of the even partitions?

Comment: The answer just depends on the values at $\pm 1$ of the Touchard polynomial (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials) $T_8(x)$.

Comment: If you are asking for the number of partitions into an even number of parts... then just how bell numbers are often calculated you could work with [Stirling Numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).  This would be just the sum of the number of parts into $k$ parts with $k$ even.

Comment: Ultimately this boils down to computing $\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{k^8}{k!}$ (that is rather large) and $\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k k^8}{k!}$ (that is rather small), so the answer ($\color{red}{2095}$) is pretty close to $\frac{B_8}{2}$.

Comment: Jack D'Aurizio thanks but how do you get 2095? I get different values for the series you given

Comment: The exponential generating function is $\cosh(e^x-1).$ This is OEIS sequence [A024430](http://oeis.org/A024430). The value for $n=8$ is $2095.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the numbers I came up with to compare any other result with:

Divide into 2 parts:
$(1,7)$: $\binom 87 =8$
$(2,6)$: $\binom 86 = 28$
$(3,5)$: $\binom 85 = 56$
$(4,4)$: $\binom 84/2 =35$

Divide into 4 parts:
$(1,1,1,5)$: $\binom 85 = 56$
$(1,1,2,4)$: $\binom 84 \binom 42= 420$
$(1,1,3,3)$: $\binom 83\binom 53/2 = 280$
$(1,2,2,3)$: $\binom 83\binom 52\binom 32/2 = 840$
$(2,2,2,2)$: $\binom 82\binom 62\binom 42\binom 22/4! = 105$

Divide into 6 parts:
$(1,1,1,1,1,3)$: $\binom 83 = 56$
$(1,1,1,1,2,2)$: $\binom 82\binom 62/2 = 210$

Divide into 8 parts:
$(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)$: $\binom 80 = 1$

Total $2095$

This could probably be written more neatly with multinomial coefficients, but the repeats still need to be divided out.